# In Packer, can you specify a path in a git repo for the Inspec provisioner?

Tags: git, packer, inspec

I would like to reference an inspec profile in a folder in the git repo. Something similar to what you can do in [Kitchen](https://github.com/inspec/kitchen-inspec):

```
  inspec_tests:
    - name: profile-name
      git: https://user@github.com/org/my_repo.git
      relative_path: inspec/sdp-base
```

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2021, it doesn't seem to be possible from the CLI:
https://github.com/inspec/inspec/issues/1237#issuecomment-767672074

But you could make a local "wrapper" profile that declares the relative path of the remote profile:

https://docs.chef.io/inspec/profiles/#git

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it to work like this using local files:

```
### Inspec testing
  provisioner "shell-local" {
    inline_shebang = "/usr/local/bin/zsh -e"
    environment_vars = ["RUBYOPT=-W0"]
    inline = [
      "print -- \"${build.SSHPrivateKey}\" > pkr_build_key",
      "chmod 0600 pkr_build_key",
      "inspec exec --sudo -i pkr_build_key -t ssh://${build.User}@${build.Host} test/inspec"
      ]
  }
```

My test files are in ./test/inspec using the standard config. So, I don't know how to do it from a URL but the workaround is obviously to have a local clone somewhere. I find that useful anyway.